# ckeditor make dialog element readonly or disable

Tags: ckeditor

I need to be able to make the URL input field in the Link Dialog window readonly or disable it.  The field gets populated when the user selects a file from the server.

Another user posted this link as a solution, http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.uiElement.html#disable   but there is no example and I can't figure out how to implement it.

[image: Link Upload Dialog Window]

Comment: It is an inbuilt dialog. Look at correspondijg plugin file and disable it

Comment: Yes, I've added      this.getInputElement().setAttribute( 'readOnly', true );   to the onload function but it's not working

Comment: I figured it out.  I posted the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the onLoad handler of the dialog you can disable it this way:

```
this.getContentElement("info", "url").disable();
```

Comment: Do you mean that you had this code working in 3.6 and now it doesn't work after upgrading to 4, or that you're starting with 4 and you can't make it work?

Comment: i started with 4 and disable() does not exist

Comment: Yes, it exists: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.uiElement-method-disable It would be very strange to change the API and remove that method without a very good reason.

Comment: Yes, it works. I've tried right now by pasting just that exact line and the url field gets disabled.

Comment: can you try it for the flash plugin? I tried it and it gave object has no such method. Or is it because i am using inline editor?

Comment: @MandeepJain I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work if you do it correctly. Given that soon after your comment here you have added another answer with basically the same answer I guess that you was trying with the wrong field names.

Comment: i think it doesnt work on onLoad events. i am using onShow and is working for me. Also i am not defining it in the plugin definition. I am doing it in my js file, but i dont think that should make a difference

Comment: Everything matters. If you are trying to use some code like the one that you posted in your answer and there are other handlers defined for that event you're overwritting them, so the dialog might stop working. You must be careful about what you do but javascript is a really powerful language so you can perform lots of tricks.

Comment: It works for me. I've put it in onLoad of a dialog for Widget.

Comment: It works for me. I've put it in onLoad of a dialog for Widget. UPDATE: sorry my mistake, onLoad only works once, onShow works always.

Comment: to get `url` field you need to write 'txtUrl` not the `url`

Answer (score 2):

this is what I ended up doing. I wrote it in my js file instead of the plugin file, but I dont think that would make a difference. I am using inline ckeditor version 4.0.2

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(event) {
    var dialogName = event.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = event.data.definition;
    //some code here

    if(dialogName == 'flash'){ // flash dialog box name
        //some code here

        dialogDefinition.onShow = function () {
            this.getContentElement("info","width").disable(); // info is the name of the tab and width is the id of the element inside the tab
            this.getContentElement("info","height").disable();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Is it also possible to "hide" it instead of just disabling?

Comment: yes, but u will have to trace down the domId ckeditor is using for that particular element and hide it using css

Answer (score 2):

You can disable url field by just one line

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getContentElement('info','txtUrl').disable()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I added this.getInputElement().setAttribute( 'readOnly', true ); to the onload funciton in ckeditor\plugins\links\dialogs\link.js. Before I was adding it to ckeditor\_source\plugins\links\dialogs\link.js. I'd still like an example of how to use the CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.uiElement disable feature, if anyone has one.

Comment: May be we can set it from config file.